# m.setTo(toArr) The method setTo(String[]) is undefined for the type Mail

Tags: email, types

```
Mail m = new Mail("mail", "password"); 
String[] toArr = {"tt@gmail.com", "tt1@gmail.com"}; 
//here comes the error!
m.setTo(toArr); 
//here comes the error!
m.setFrom("christian.schartner@gmail.com"); 
//here comes the error!
m.setSubject("using my Mail JavaMail wrapper from an Android device."); 
//on m.setBody is no error!
m.setBody("Email body.");
```

I get an error in eclipse when I paste this code.

Comment: What error and on what line?

Comment: For example in the line m.setTo(toArr) the text setTo(toArr) ist red underlined in eclipse. I mean eclipse (Java) does not know "setTo" or "setFrom" etc.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I had the same issue,

> **The method setTo(String[]) is undefined for the type Mail**

just be sure to have the `activation.jar`, `additionnal.jar` and `mail.jar` files of the `JavaMail Api` inside your `/libs` project folder.